# The range of the complex function $f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

how can I find the range of the function $$f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$ over the unit disk $\{z\in C;|z|=1\}$. I could not get anything by writting $z$ as $x+iy$ or $re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT :

Since $|z|=1\iff z\bar z=1,$ we have
$$1-z=z\bar z-z=z(\bar z-1).$$
Hence, we have
$$\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{z}{z^2(\bar z-1)^2}=\frac{1}{z(\bar z\bar z-2\bar z+1)}=\frac{1}{\bar z-2+z}=\frac{1}{(x-iy)-2+(x+iy)}.$$

Comment: So the range is $C-(-\infty,1/4]$? Thank you.

Comment: $(-\infty,-1/4]$, isn't?

Comment: Oh. yes, I misprint it.