# Range of the function $f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ over the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the range of the function $$f(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$ over the unit disk $\{z\in \mathbb{C};|z|<1\}$ is $\mathbb{C} \setminus \big(-\infty, -\frac{1}{4}\big]$.

I was able to prove that the range of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \big(-\infty, -\frac{1}{4}\big]$.

I'm having issues with the other inclusion.

I tried to solve $\frac{z}{(z-1)²} = w$ and impose that $|z|<1$ but it's not working, I can't get that $w$ should be in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \big(-\infty, -\frac{1}{4}\big]$.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620298/the-range-of-the-complex-function-fz-fracz1-z2-on-the-unit-disk) shows that if $|z|=1$ then $f(z) \in (-\infty, -\frac{1}{4}\big]$.
I couldn't see if this  helps or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Koebe quarter theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjx2dfux73UAhUb0IMKHfCYDFoQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FKoebe_quarter_theorem&usg=AFQjCNHQx2w4Kh3dzVJ2I5wM4yB70Hq6mw)

Comment: The range can't be $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, - 1/4)$ as that is not an open set.

Comment: @zhw You're right, actually the  range is $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, -1/4]$

Comment: I edited the question. Now it's correct I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is a rational function of order (or degree) $2$. Thus every value in $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$ is attained exactly twice on $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$, counting multiplicity. Further, $f$ satisfies the functional equation

$$f\biggl(\frac{1}{z}\biggr) = f(z).$$

Hence

$$f(\mathbb{D}) = f\bigl((\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\})\setminus \overline{D}\bigr) = (\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}) \setminus f(\partial \mathbb{D}).$$

So knowing what $f$ does on the unit circle definitely helps determining $f(\mathbb{D})$.